# JQuery Clyp Auto-embed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

This function finds links from Clyp.it and offers users a link to embed the content. Please let me know what you think of it. It works, but probably has some redundancies and inefficiencies.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var clyplinks = $('a[href^="https://clyp.it/"]').filter(function() {
        return this.innerHTML.match(/(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/);
    });
    $(clyplinks).each(function(index) {

        var x = null;
        var id = $(this).attr("href").split("it/")[1];
        var e = $('<a class="embed" id="' + id + index +'" href="#"> [embed]</a>').insertAfter($(this));
        e.click(function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            if (x != 1) {
                $(this).after('<div id="clyp' + id + index + '"><iframe width="259" height="160" src="https://clyp.it/' + id + '/widget" frameborder="0" ></iframe></div>')
                $(e).html('<a class="embed" id="' + id + index +'" href="#"> [remove]</a>')
                x = 1;
                console.log('embed' + x + ' ' + index);
            } else {
                $('#clyp' + id + index).detach();
                $(e).html('<a class="embed" id="' + id + index +'" href="#"> [embed]</a>')
                x = null;
                console.log('yay' + x + ' ' + index);

            }

        });

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://clyp.it/5e0dmibw" rel="nofollow" target="_blank">https://clyp.it/5e0dmibw</a>
```

JSFiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/1svgq6g4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Regex

The regex used is `/(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/`.
Since, here you're checking if the string is URL and not using to extract data from string, capturing groups can be removed.

`[\w]`: Match word character(alphanumeric character and underscore). This can be written as `\w` by removing character class.

I'll also suggest to use [word boundary](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) and use of `i`-case-insensitive flag to match both uppercase and/or lowercase alphabets.

```
/\bhttps:\/\/clyp.it\/\w{8}\b/
```

### `match` vs `test`

[`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) is used to extract data from string. To check if string follows particular pattern, use [`RegExp#test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test). `test` is faster than `match`.

See [regex.test V.S. string.match to know if a string matches a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10940137/2025923)

```
$('a[href^="https://clyp.it/"]').filter(function() {
    return /https:\/\/clyp.it\/\w{8}/i.test(this.innerHTML);
});
```

### Variable Naming

Variable names should be self-descriptive. I'll recommend to read https://github.com/ryanmcdermott/clean-code-javascript#variables.

1. `clyplinks` can be just `links` or `clypLinks`(camelCase)
2. `x` can be renamed to `flag` and used as boolean(`true`/`false`)
3. `e` should be `el` if you like short names or `element`. As it is jQuery wrapped element, it is common to use `$` as prefix in variable name- `$element`.

### Event binding

For single link, this will work. If there are multiple links on the page to bind events on dynamic elements [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) can be used. When using event delegation, the code should be moved outside of `each` so that event is not bound multiple times.

The syntax is

```
$(parentElementSelector).on(event, childElements, callbackFunction)
```

In this case, as there is no common parent element which contain all the links, we can use `document`

```
$(document).on('click', '.embed', function(event) {
```

### Using `data-*`

Instead of using a flag to store the status of link, HTML5 custom `data-*` can be used. So, on click of link, first check if variable value is set and depending on the value perform action. To read the value of `data-*` attribute use [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

```
// Inside click handler
if ($(this).data('state') === 'embedded') {
    // Already embedded
    // Remove
} else {
    // Not embedded
    // Add
}

// Change the value
$(this).data('state', function(i, value) {
    // switch the value
    return value === 'embedded' ? 'not embedded' : 'embedded';
});
```

After doing these changes, previous code will not work. Inside the handler `$(e).html(` is used to change the link text. Note that [`html()`](https://api.jquery.com/html/) will set the `innerHTML` of the element and not replace it. If you inspect the Embed link by clicking on it, you'll notice that link is nested. To solve this, just use `$(this).html('[remove]')`. Also, note that `$(this)` inside event handler refer to the element on which the event has occurred.

### jQuery Wrapping & Method Chaining

`clyplinks` is already jQuery collection of element. There is no need of wrapping it in jQuery again.

jQuery allows to chain most of the methods.

```
var clyplinks = $('a[href^="https://clyp.it/"]').filter(function() {
    return this.innerHTML.match(/(https:\/\/clyp.it\/)([\w]{8})/);
});
$(clyplinks).each(function(index) {
```

can be written as

```
$(someSelector).filter(function() {
    return ...;
}).each(function(index) {
```

This also eliminates `clyplinks` variable.

---

Below things are also important

1. Code Formatting: You may install plugin/package in editor/IDE
2. Missing Semi-colons: Use jslint/jshint